# getContentResolver().insert(…, …); returning NULL for Notification Ringtones

Tags: android

getContentResolver().insert(…, …); returning NULL for Notification Ringtones when the setRingtone function is called onBootCompleted of device, otherwise it works fine :

here is setRingTone method code:

```
File file = new File(path, filename);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Tone");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "test");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri u = getContentResolver().insert(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath()), values);
```

Comment: Is there anything displayed in logcat? Maybe a SQLiteConstraintException?